# Kubeflow installation on existing EKS cluster with cert-manager already installed

Tags: amazon-eks, kubeflow, cert-manager

I have an EKS cluster (1.18 version)in the pre-production environment.
Now I would like to use this cluster to install Kubeflow (1.4 version).
Unfortunately, when I try to install it with the `kfctl apply -V -f kfctl_aws.yaml`
I get this error:

```
WARN[0024] Encountered error applying application cert-manager-crds:  (kubeflow.error): Code 500 with message: Apply.Run : [error when applying patch:
{"metadata":{"annotations":{"cert-manager.io/inject-ca-from-secret":null,"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1\",\"kind\":\"CustomResourceDefinition\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"certificaterequests.cert-manager.io\"},\"spec\":{\"additionalPrinterColumns\":[{\"JSONPath\":\".status.conditions[?(@.type==\\\"Ready\\\")].status\",\"name\":\"Ready\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"JSONPath\":\".spec.issuerRef.name\",\"name\":\"Issuer\",\"priority\":1,\"type\":\"string\"},{\"JSONPath\":\".status.conditions[?(@.type==\\\"Ready\\\")].message\",\"name\":\"Status\",\"priority\":1,\"type\":\"string\"},{\"JSONPath\":\".metadata.creationTimestamp\",\"description\":\"CreationTimestamp is a timestamp representing the server time when this object was created. It is not guaranteed to be set in happens-before order across separate operations. Clients may not set this value. It is represented in RFC3339 form and is in UTC.\",\"name\":\"Age\",\"type\":\"date\"}],\"group\":\"cert-manager.io\",\"names\":{\"kind\":\"CertificateRequest\",\"listKind\":\"CertificateRequestList\",\"plural\":\"certificaterequests\",\"shortNames\":[\"cr\",\"crs\"],\"singular\":\"certificaterequest\"},\"scope\":\"Namespaced\",\"subresources\":{\"status\":{}},\"validation\":{\"openAPIV3Schema\":{\"description\":\"CertificateRequest is a type to represent a Certificate Signing Request\",\"properties\":{\"apiVersion\":{\"description\":\"APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation of an object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest internal value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#resources\",\"type\":\"string\"},\"kind\":{\"description\":\"Kind is a string value representing the REST resource this object represents. Servers may infer this from the endpoint the client submits requests to. Cannot be updated.....
```

Could it be due because I already have cert-manager installed? If so how I can skip this step from the installation process?